# Expose container port to Host using Docker for Windows in Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I've reading [docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/) and trying to create a simple container and expose 1 port.

In my example, I have an application that listen on **TCP** port `9595` inside the container and I want to access it from outside world (i.e. the host of the container) on port `9090`.

When creating the container I have `"ExposedPorts": { "9595/tcp: {}" }` and the `"PortBindings": { "9595/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "9090" }] }`.

So, if I access from the Host machine `http://container_internal_ip:9595` it works! However, when I access `http://localhost:9090`, which is what I expect using this port map feature, it doesn't work...

While running `docker port containerID` I have `9595/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9090` and that should means, `when connecting to any IP on the host, at port 9090, forward to the container in port 9595`.

So, what is wrong here? Why can't I connect to 9090?

I appreciate any clarifications.

Comment: The question doesn't have enough information. We need at least the docker command, what image is using or the Dockerfile. Windows containers or Linux containers?

Comment: **Docker Remote API** against what docker engine? Windows containers? Linux container? You cannot run a container without a base image. What image? You called the **Docker Remote API** how you called it? It is a resfful right? What command did you use? I cannot **KNOW** about what you are asking if you don't give **ENOUGH** information.

Comment: Sorry,I don't meant to be rude Carlos, but none of your comments were relevant to question. It doesn't matter to the question what is the image. What matters is that according to the API documentation, I have port 9090 exposed to outside the container and mapped to port 9595 inside the container and that isn't working. Netsh will not affect anything on the container behavior or configuration.

Answer (score 5):

**Please post the docker command you are using.**

You need an special treatment if you use Docker Toolbox or Docker for Windows. You should see **localhost** without problems (if your container is Linux). If you want your container be visible from outside, try this with Elevated Power Shell:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=yourip listenport=9090 connectaddress=10.0.75.1 connectport=9090
```

If your container is Windows however you won't see **localhost** and you need to use the container internal address:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" <cointainerid>
```

Reference: https://www.docker.com/blog/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/

Regards

Comment: Hello Carlos, yes, I'm using latest docker for windows beta on win10 and `docker info` return `"ServerVersion":"1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta"` And according to Docker API v1.24 (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#create-a-container) the `PortBindings` indeed exist.

Comment: You need extra port redirection for docker for Windows. I will update the answer

Comment: In fact I used `docker inspect` It explains the difference in nomenclature.

Comment: I dont think that it is the way. Do you have any official docs to support that answer? Why should I need a windows port forward if the other port is currently working? Also where did u saw fatal error? Also docker inspect return the same nomenclature, no difference.

Comment: Well my answer is based on: https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/ specially this part: To access the running app from the host running the containers (for example when running on Windows 10 or if opening browser on Windows Server 2016 system running Docker engine) use the container IP and port 5000. localhost will not work. I am assuming you are using Windows containers. They only thing we can do **assume**, because you don't post your docker command, dockerfile, even I asked for

Comment: Carlos, there is no docker command, that is why I'm not posting anything. I'm using the API. Regarding the port forward and the link you posted, I've already read it. It mention how to make dockerd to listen on the TCP port and not just the named pipe so a remove client can connect the **host** thru the docker client. I'm not talking about it. I'm talking about having the container exposed to the outside world.

Comment: Sorry but in your question you said `http://localhost:9090`. I don't see anything in your question about exposing to the outside world. The netsh command allows you expose your Windows container to the outside world

Comment: Hey Carlos, your proxy add command did the trick for me. With this answer being ~3 years old, is this still the preferred solution? I haven't been able to find any updated solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The port really is being exposed to the 'outside world' as expected, it just happens to be inaccessible from the container host machine itself on the loopback interface (localhost or 127.0.0.1) due to a current windows networking limitation. Rather than trying to access it via the loopback interface on the container host, try to access it from another machine on the network, using the container host ip and the containers exposed port number.

There is a good writeup for this at https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/