# Running Spring boot application inside docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I have created an image out of my simple spring-boot application and set the port to 7000 for the tomcat , when I run the image and try to hit the service in my local I am not getting any response.

here are the contents of the dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD  /target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Am I missing something here ( I am new to docker and I just used the file in spring boot sample docker and created the image and stuck here.)

Comment: Please add more information like which what error are you getting, are you using virtual box to run docker?

Comment: yes , docker with hyper v - errror like "This site can't be Reached"

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: not yet , if it helps you ( docker installed in windows 10 )

Comment: My problem got solved by this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349893/expose-container-port-to-host-using-docker-for-windows-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

Apart from publishing the port from docker as mentioned by @Van0SS you need to create a port forwarding rule as well.
Open virtualbox and Navigate to VM -> Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> Port forwarding
Create a new rule:

```
Name : <Anything - Purpose of port>
Protocol: TCP
HostIP: 127.0.0.1
Host port: 7000
Guest Port: 7000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is only one problem, but at least you have to *publish* your port in docker. To do so run the container with flag:

> -p 7000:7000

Try access on :7000 port.

Comment: Please share which manual did you use and where demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar came from.

Comment: Have you created port forwarding rule in VirtualBox?

Comment: @Pramod no please tell me if in case i need to do , i watched a youtube tutorial in which i followed all the steps similar to that ( i installed docker ce for windows , and later installed hyper-v when it prompted me )

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:
  EXPOSE: 7000
to your docker file, and keep an eye on the console log info when running the docker image to see on which port your app is being served.

Useful Ref:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlSup_eelYE

Best of luck!