# Docker for Windows - Can not connect to the MongoDB on Ubuntu Container from Windows host

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-for-windows

I use Docker for Windows and started a Ubuntu Container.
The Container use my default bridge network. I install for tests the MongoDB and have no access via the localhost:27017 on my Windows host.

My configuration have a map to this port and I use the default bridge network. Other container with the same configuration works. As example the official mongodb container works perfect.

## My steps:

- docker run -it -p 27017:27017 --name MongoExercise ubuntu
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y mongodb
- service mongodb start

The ping to the containers IP dosn´t work also.

Comment: Either use Windows docker (docker pull stefanscherer/mongo-windows) or may b duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349893/expose-container-port-to-host-using-docker-for-windows-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that is embarrassing...
MongoDB v3.6.3 on Ubuntu have a new default permission to the network access..
Only localhost is allowed.. you must set the IP address from your host system or allow all for tests with:

```
mongod --bind_ip_all
```